# How should I write my name - Shivam Mukherjee - in Katakana?

Tags: katakana, names, written-language

I'm being asked to fill my name in Katakana in an application form for a language school in Japan.

I'm currently going with シワム・ムカージ since:

1. The ワ sound is closest to the inflection on the -v sound so I avoided using バ.
2. The ム at the end of my first name reflects the -m sound. Had I gone with
   ン it would lead to a lot of weird mispronunciations (in my opinion).
3. Omitting the -r sound in "Mukherjee" reflects the etymology (in my opinion) of my surname, which is actually a simplified version of "Mukhopadhyay" meaning "Head Teacher" in Sanskrit.

Any insight about this would be most helpful.

IPA: http://ipa-reader.xyz/?text=%CA%83%C9%AAv%C9%90m%20m%CA%8Akh%C9%90%CA%80d%CD%A1%CA%92i&voice=Raveena is a close approximation but not accurate enough.

Audio: https://sndup.net/7d54

EDIT:

I thought of new candidates for my surname:

1. ムクッジェ/ムコッジェ - from "Mukhujje/Mukhojje" which is an early contraction of "Mukhopadhyay"
2. ムカッジ - more modern, fitting with "Mukherjee" but stressing on the -j instead of elongating the second syllable.

These are based on the same premise as point 3 from my OP where I'm trying to fit with the etymology.

Answer (score 1):

ムカージ sound a metathesis to me. I mean it's bit hard for to distinguish ムカジー, ムカージ,ムカジ. Without the elongation ー between カ and ジ is the most natural to me. (i.e it sounds ムカジ to me.)

As for 1. We do not distinguish Va and Ba. So it's more close to Wa as you think.

As for 2, if you want to avoid "Liaison", I think ム is easy to separate your given name and surname.

As for 3. it’s natural for Japanese to not pronounce the “r” sound. So never mind.

Comment: I wanted to emulate the stress one would usually give while pronouncing Mukherjee - it's on the second syllable.

Comment: ムカジ is better than ムカージ. Cut　カット is more stressed than Card　カード for カ.

Comment: I got the idea for my OP edit based on this!